# rails 5 sidekiq jobs keep referencing old class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, jobs

At first I had a class CastingMailer with a method email_coupon_sent, I created the class CouponMailer with everything that mailer needs and I put the method email_coupon_sent in that class, in my job I call CouponMailer.email_coupon_sent and sidekiq tells me in the log 2017-02-14T15:42:05.066Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `email_coupon_sent' for CastingMailer:Class, why sidekiq keep looking for email_coupon_sent in CastingMailer class.

Code

admin_controller.rb

```
@coupon.give!
CouponSentJob.perform_later(@user.profileable, @coupon)
```

coupon_sent_job.rb

```
def perform(profile, coupon)
  # Send coupon to user
  Notification.notify_coupon_sent(profile, coupon)
  CouponMailer.email_coupon_sent(profile, coupon).deliver_now
end
```

coupon_mailer.rb

```
def email_coupon_sent(profile, coupon)
  @profile = profile
  @coupon = coupon
  mail(to: @profile.user.email, subject: I18n.t('views.mailers.coupon.coupon_sent.subject'))
end
```

views/coupon_mailer

```
email_coupon_sent.html.erb
email_coupon_sent.text.erb
```

sidekiq.log

```
2017-02-14T15:42:04.980Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 CouponSentJob JID-0b611e12bcd38bd3fc87b86c INFO: start
2017-02-14T15:42:05.065Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 CouponSentJob JID-0b611e12bcd38bd3fc87b86c INFO: fail: 0.085 sec
2017-02-14T15:42:05.066Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":       {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"CouponSentJob","queue":"default","args":   [{"job_class":"CouponSentJob","job_id":"d6f830a6-db9f-4af8-bb0c-83580536a8db","queue_name":"default","priority":null,"arguments":  [{"_aj_globalid":"gid://cubamodela/ProfileModel/4"},{"_aj_globalid":"gid://cubamodela/Coupon/6"}],"locale":"en"}  ],"retry":true,"jid":"0b611e12bcd38bd3fc87b86c","created_at":1487086924.9707098,"enqueued_at":1487086924.9742587,"error_message":"undefined   method `email_coupon_sent' for     CastingMailer:Class","error_class":"NoMethodError","failed_at":1487086925.0644813,"retry_count":0},"jobstr":"{\"class\":  \"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper\",\"wrapped\":\"CouponSentJob\",\"queue\":\"default\",\"args\":[{\"job_class\":  \"CouponSentJob\",\"job_id\":\"d6f830a6-db9f-4af8-bb0c-83580536a8db\",\"queue_name\":\"default\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":  [{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://cubamodela/ProfileModel/4\"},{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://cubamodela/Coupon/6\"}],\"locale\":\"en\"}],\"retry\":true,  \"jid\":\"0b611e12bcd38bd3fc87b86c\",\"created_at\":1487086924.9707098,\"enqueued_at\":1487086924.9742587}"}
2017-02-14T15:42:05.066Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `email_coupon_sent' for CastingMailer:Class
2017-02-14T15:42:05.066Z 7344 TID-ynsk0 WARN: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionmailer-5.0.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:565:in   `method_missing'
/home/deployer/cubamodela/app/jobs/coupon_sent_job.rb:6:in `perform'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activejob-5.0.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:34:in `block in perform_now'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
```

in my CastingMailer currently there is not email_coupon_sent method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it you production or development environment? Have you restarted your sidekiq after changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

The job saves the class and method name it needs to call.  You can't just rename a class if there are jobs that still reference it in Redis.  You have to ensure there are no more jobs referencing the name too.  Easiest thing to do is flush the entire Redis database but that wipes out everything.